# SQL Server: Link two tables and get the rows of second table as columns in the result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm a novice at SQL. 
Kindly help .

I have two tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [tblCg](
    [c_id] [char](1) NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [pk_tblCg] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
 (
    [c_id] ASC
 )
)

CREATE TABLE [tblTR](
    [c_id] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [q] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [tdate] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [t_res] [char](4) NULL
 CONSTRAINT [pk_tblTR] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
 (
    [c_id] ASC,
    [q] ASC
 )
)


INSERT INTO [tblCg] VALUES ('1')
INSERT INTO [tblCg] VALUES ('2')
INSERT INTO [tblCg] VALUES ('3')
INSERT INTO [tblCg] VALUES ('4')

/* Date is the same for a given c_id, may differ across c_id's */
INSERT INTO [tblTR] VALUES ('1', 'R1', getdate(), '1.01')
INSERT INTO [tblTR] VALUES ('1', 'R2', getdate(), '55.6')
INSERT INTO [tblTR] VALUES ('1', 'R3', getdate(), '48.2')
INSERT INTO [tblTR] VALUES ('1', 'R4', getdate(), '9.44')

INSERT INTO [tblTR] VALUES ('2', 'R1', DATEADD(month, 1, getdate()), '5.26')
INSERT INTO [tblTR] VALUES ('2', 'R2', DATEADD(month, 1, getdate()), '678')
INSERT INTO [tblTR] VALUES ('2', 'R3', DATEADD(month, 1, getdate()), '48.7')
INSERT INTO [tblTR] VALUES ('2', 'R4', DATEADD(month, 1, getdate()), '4.26')

INSERT INTO [tblTR] VALUES ('3', 'R1', DATEADD(month, 2, getdate()), '6.23')
INSERT INTO [tblTR] VALUES ('3', 'R2', DATEADD(month, 2, getdate()), '2465')
INSERT INTO [tblTR] VALUES ('3', 'R3', DATEADD(month, 2, getdate()), '52.5')
INSERT INTO [tblTR] VALUES ('3', 'R4', DATEADD(month, 2, getdate()), '61.2')

INSERT INTO [tblTR] VALUES ('4', 'R1', DATEADD(month, 3, getdate()), '5.12')
INSERT INTO [tblTR] VALUES ('4', 'R2', DATEADD(month, 3, getdate()), '654')
INSERT INTO [tblTR] VALUES ('4', 'R3', DATEADD(month, 3, getdate()), '8.54')
INSERT INTO [tblTR] VALUES ('4', 'R4', DATEADD(month, 3, getdate()), '8.16')
```

I need an output like this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbWpB.jpg

Each c_id has one date (tdate) and up to a maximum of 4 results (t_res).
Output can contain NULLs, if there is no corresponding data, as the front-end report can handle them. (similar to OUTER JOINs).
Kindly let me know if you need any more information.

My main requirement here is to get 4 rows of [tblTR] as 4 columns + 1 date, for each c_id.

EDIT:
Since this question was marked as duplicate and redirected to a URL that almost answers my question, I tried to incorporate the same to my query but it returns only one row.
This is the query I came up with, on the same lines as in the example at the redirected URL.

```
select R1, R2, R3, R4 
from
(
    select [t_res], [q]
    from [tblTR]
) d
pivot
(
    max(t_res)
    for [q] in (R1, R2, R3, R4)
) piv;
```

Comment: When does the homework need to be in by?

Comment: So you want one column for each row in a month/date? Group by date and use `PIVOT`.

Comment: @Siyual: I just added the query that I have come up with, until now.

Comment: @kevchadders: Ha ha.. Its not my "homework". I am a .NET (mostly)front-end developer and I occasionally have to deal with simple SQL, involving joins, at the most. This one was outta my league (trying to learn, though ;) )

Comment: @Shreesha The problem with your query is you aren't using JOIn between the two tables - see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92807/2

Comment: Hi @bluefeet, This is the query I am using now http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92807/3/0.
Is this different from the one you suggested? (I am not that good with intricacies of SQL)
And btw, thanks for redirecting me to the right question that helped solve my issue.

Comment: @Shreesha I'm glad that you were able to solve it.